# duplicates in jest tests memory snapshot

Tags: memory, jestjs, memory-leaks

While running jest in watch mode, and inspecting the memory using Chrome Devtools with this command:

`node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch --runInBand --logHeapUsage`

I see duplicates content in memory snapshot:
[image: memory contains libraries duplicates]

Tests are using a lot of memory so it may be related. How is that possible and how to prevent it?

Precision: as soon as more tests are run, the more duplicate entries there are.

Comment: Which version of jest are you using? I have the same problem. Did you find anything?

Comment: nothing found I am using 29.4.3

Comment: Yeah, couldn't find a solution either. Probably related to https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11956

Im using workerIdleMemoryLimit to avoid it eating all my memory.

Comment: yes it is seen on node 16 and it's worst on node 18